# fill mySQL database with text file information

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, sql

I have been using `awk` and some cisco commands to get information about devices connected to a network, the script connects via telnet to certain device, take the `IP`, `serial number`, and the `name` (device id) of this device and generate a text file like this:

```
SN: FDO1129Z9ZQ
Barragan_3750
IP address: 148.228.4.197
```

Then it asks for the devices connected to this equipment and generates a second file like this:

```
Device ID: BIOTERIO
IP address: 148.228.83.140
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/6
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: P7K08UR      

Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
IP address: 148.228.4.193
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/1
Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/23
SN: H006K024       

Device ID: LAB_PESADO
IP address: 148.228.131.133
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/11
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: FNS174002FY    

Device ID: Arquitectura_Salones
IP address: 148.228.135.33
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/9
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/49
SN: FNS14420544    

Device ID: CIVIL_253
IP address: 148.228.132.256
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/4
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/52
SN: H006K042    

Device ID: Arquitectura
IP address: 148.228.134.456
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/3
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: H006K044      

Device ID: ING_CIVIL
IP address: 148.228.133.234
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/7
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
SN: H006K011       

Device ID: ING_CIVIL_DIR
IP address: 148.228.4.987
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/10
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
SN: FNS16361SW1    

Device ID: Ingenieria_Posgrado
IP address: 148.228.137.343
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/8
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: H006K432   

Device ID: Biblio_Barragan
IP address: 148.228.136.45
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: 00000MTC1444080D

Device ID: Electronica_Edif_3
IP address: 148.228.130.345
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/5
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: FNS11190FRT
```

I need this information to be placed in a `MySQL` database, so I have created a DB with two tables like this:

```
+------------------+
| Tables_in_db_cdp |
+------------------+
| Trelaciones      |
| dispositivos     |
+------------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE dispositivos;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sn         | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| device_id  | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_address | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> DESCRIBE Trelaciones
    -> ;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Device_SN_O | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Device_SN_D | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Interface   | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Port_ID     | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I need to fill this database with the files' info, but honestly I don't know how to do that, I supposed I need to make a cycle into a script, but that's all,

Any help?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE: using the codes of the accepted answer I've got this result:

```
Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,P7K08UQ         
,GigabitEthernet1/0/6,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,H006K022        
,GigabitEthernet1/0/1,Ethernet7/23
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,FNS174002FT     
,GigabitEthernet1/0/11,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,FNS14420533     
,GigabitEthernet1/0/9,GigabitEthernet0/49
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,H006K021        
,GigabitEthernet1/0/4,GigabitEthernet1/0/52
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,H006K083        
,GigabitEthernet1/0/3,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,H006K032        
,GigabitEthernet1/0/7,GigabitEthernet0/2
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,FNS16361SG0     
,GigabitEthernet1/0/10,GigabitEthernet0/2
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,H006K040        
,GigabitEthernet1/0/8,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,00000MTC1444080Z
,GigabitEthernet1/0/2,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZJ
,FNS11190FLE     
,GigabitEthernet1/0/5,GigabitEthernet0/1
```

When I use "`load data infile`" the information is filled in wrong fields.

I have noticed that if I open the .cvs file with "writer" the separators and break lines are correct, but not with gedit:

[image: both are the same file]

If I edit the .cvs file manually and place commas and break lines correctly "`load data infile`" function works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating `INSERT` statements is messy, an easier way is to convert your files to CSV with `awk`, then use `mysqlimport` to import the results into the relevant tables.

For the first table the conversion could be something like this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        RS = "\n\n"
        FS = "\n"
        OFS = ","
        print "sn,device_id,ip_address"
    }
    {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            split($i, a, ": ");
            k[a[1]] = a[2]
        }
        print k["SN"], k["Device ID"], k["IP address"]
    }' file2.txt > table1.csv
```

The results should look like this:

```
sn,device_id,ip_address
P7K08UR,BIOTERIO,148.228.83.140
H006K024,N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL),148.228.4.193
FNS174002FY,LAB_PESADO,148.228.131.133
FNS14420544,Arquitectura_Salones,148.228.135.33
H006K042,CIVIL_253,148.228.132.256
H006K044,Arquitectura,148.228.134.456
H006K011,ING_CIVIL,148.228.133.234
FNS16361SW1,ING_CIVIL_DIR,148.228.4.987
H006K432,Ingenieria_Posgrado,148.228.137.343
00000MTC1444080D,Biblio_Barragan,148.228.136.45
FNS11190FRT,Electronica_Edif_3,148.228.130.345
```

Then, assuming I understand what `Device_SN_O` and `Device_SN_D` are supposed to be, for the second table you might do something like this:

```
awk -v orig=$(awk '$1=="SN:" {print $2}' file1.txt) '
    BEGIN {
        RS = "\n\n"                                               
        FS = "\n"                                                 
        OFS = ","                                                 
        print "Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID"         
    }                                                             

    {                                                             
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {                                    
            split($i, a, ": ");                                   
            k[a[1]] = a[2]                                        
        }                                                         
        print orig, k["SN"], k["Interface"], k["Port ID (outgoing port)"]
    }' file2.txt > table2.csv
```

The results would be this:

```
Device_SN_O,Device_SN_D,Interface,Port_ID
FDO1129Z9ZQ,P7K08UR,GigabitEthernet1/0/6,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZQ,H006K024,GigabitEthernet1/0/1,Ethernet7/23
FDO1129Z9ZQ,FNS174002FY,GigabitEthernet1/0/11,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZQ,FNS14420544,GigabitEthernet1/0/9,GigabitEthernet0/49
FDO1129Z9ZQ,H006K042,GigabitEthernet1/0/4,GigabitEthernet1/0/52
FDO1129Z9ZQ,H006K044,GigabitEthernet1/0/3,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZQ,H006K011,GigabitEthernet1/0/7,GigabitEthernet0/2
FDO1129Z9ZQ,FNS16361SW1,GigabitEthernet1/0/10,GigabitEthernet0/2
FDO1129Z9ZQ,H006K432,GigabitEthernet1/0/8,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZQ,00000MTC1444080D,GigabitEthernet1/0/2,GigabitEthernet0/1
FDO1129Z9ZQ,FNS11190FRT,GigabitEthernet1/0/5,GigabitEthernet0/1
```

Then you could [import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071108) the CSV files into MySQL.

Comment: looks like a good way to do it to me

Comment: @Sato your answer is awesome, I have noticed that depending on the text editor I use the format is showed, only if I open it with "open office writer"  looks in the correct order, otherwise line breaks and spaces are different than in your example. 
should I do something about it?

Comment: @CesarAlejandroVillegasYepez I'm afraid I can't parse what you're saying.  My post doesn't mention editors, Open Office, line breaks, spaces...

Comment: @SatoKatsura I just update the question, I hope it's clear now.
thanks again.

Comment: @CesarAlejandroVillegasYepez This seems to be a line ending issue.  Your device produces files with CRLF (a.k.a. DOS / Windows) line endings, while the scripts above (and most other UNIX utilities) expect LF endings.  You could use one of the many `dos2unix` utilities to fix them, or, if you have a modern `sed`, just run `sed -i 's/\n//' file1.txt file2.txt`.